# Creating a container with a variable port

Tags: couchdb, port, docker

I want to create an image for couchdb, to run multiple couchdb instances. For reasons that are a bit long to clarify, I want the couchdb instance *in the container* to listen to a non default port, which is also not known at image definition time, since this will be a container parameter.

From the host I would run the container with:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 10000:30000 --name couchdb -e COUCHDB_PORT=30000 my/couchdb
```

Which would make the port in the container (30000), where couchdb is listening, to be reachable through port 10000 in the host. This port should a per-container paramenter.

This way from the container I could do:

```
curl -X GET localhost:30000
```

And from the host I could do:

```
curl -X GET localhost:10000
```

Both requests would be hitting the same couchdb server.

Setting up the container has been easy (it is just a matter of processing the environment variable to automatically edit the couchdb config file), but now I have reached a blocking problem. At the end of the Dockerfile I have:

```
# the default couchdb port, which in my case is not
#     known at image creation time
EXPOSE 5984
```

Apparently I need to expose the port where my service is running inside the container, but I do not know that when creating the image. This is a run-time parameter, which will differ from container to container.

How can I expose a port when starting up the container?

Comment: I don't understand why you need the daemon inside the container to have a non-standard port. Can you clarify that a bit more?

Each container has its own virtual network interface

Comment: That is application dependent. Sorry, but it would be very difficult for me to explain the rationale behind it. But the question is clear I think: how to define a container which exposes a port which is only known when the container starts-up?

Comment: can you post your dockerfile @jeckyll2hide? or what's docker image are you using for couchdb?

Comment: @jeckyll2hide, I don't understand, the couchdb wake up with default port 5984; then if you need various containers with couchdb, the only configuration needed it's execute: `docker run -d -p 5984:30000 --name couchdb my/couchdb`, `docker run -d -p 5984:30001 --name couchdb my/couchdb`,`docker run -d -p 5984:30002 --name couchdb my/couchdb`

Comment: unless I need the port in the container itself to be a different one ... for example, to setup a replication which was working before in "normal" (non-docker) environment with several couchdb instances running in different ports. Now I want to keep my previous setup, but running the different instances with docker. Whenever a couchdb running in port 5985 was replicating to itself (to another database, for partitioning for example), it was replicating to port 5985. Now ... it does not work anymore because the instance is running inside docker in the default port.

Comment: From outside it is still 5985 (because I do the port mapping that you have correctly suggested), but from inside docker (from the point of view of couchdb itself), it is 5984. That means that all world sees this couchdb in port 5985, except couchdb itself that sees it as 5984. This inconsistency gives me lots of trouble, and it means I will have to rewrite an important part of my backend code. Or that I will have to forget about running several couchdbs in parallel with docker. What I want is couchdb inside docker to listen to 5985 too, to make my life easy: the same port outside and inside.

Comment: And, by the way, it is not only a problem with several parallels couchdbs: as soon as you want to make your couchdb available in a different port (say you want to "hide" your couchdb in a non-standard port), then with docker you either prepare an image for each different port, or run it in the standard port and do port mapping in the host. The first option does not scale (a different image for each containter with a different port), and the second causes the problem that I have described above. I guess couchdb is special, compared to other services, because it must talk to itself sometimes.

Comment: be careful @jeckyll2hide, currently with docker it's to hard manage a cluster of DBs + data containers, because persistence with docker it's so complicated...I suggest you reconsider the creation of cluster of coucheDB. Also, you can fallow a progress of project https://clusterhq.com/ for these porpouse.